# how to write condition to check csv file data which is not in the database table in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, csv

**My controller looks**

```
public function importcsv() 
{

    $data['menu'] = $this->AdminModel->get_menu();
    $data['error'] = '';    //initialize image upload error array to empty

    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv';
    $config['max_size'] = '1000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);


    // If upload failed, display error
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

        $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
    } 
    else 
    {
        $file_data = $this->upload->data();
        $file_path =  './assets/uploads/'.$file_data['file_name'];

        if ($this->csvimport->get_array($file_path)) 
        {

            $csv_array = $this->csvimport->get_array($file_path);
            foreach ($csv_array as $row) 
            {


                $data1['mid']=$row['mid'];
                $data1['category']=$row['category'];
                $data1['name']=$row['name'];
                $data1['price']=$row['price'];
                $data1['description']=$row['description'];


                    if($this->db->where('mid', $data1['mid']))
                    {

                         $this->db->update('menu', $data1);
                    }
                        if($this->db->where("mid <>",$data1['mid']))
                        {


                            $this->db->insert('menu', $data1);
                        }



            }        

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Csv Data Imported Succesfully');
            redirect(base_url().'Admin/menu');

        } 
        else 
        {
            $data['error'] = "Error occured";
            $this->load->view('csvindex', $data);
        }

    }
}
```

*using the condition*

```
   if($this->db->where('mid', $data1['mid']))
    {

         $this->db->update('menu', $data1);
    }
```

I can update the **menu** table content where *mid* is equal to csv file *mid*  **($data1['mid'])**. its work fine.

my need is I have to insert record when **mid** in the **csv file** not in the **menu table** . for that I use a condition

```
    if($this->db->where("mid <>",$data1['mid']))
    {
        $this->db->insert('menu', $data1);
    }
```

but Its not working, it work as when if the **mid** in the **csv file** not in the **menu table** , then it insert whole csv file content into the table.

My need is I have to insert only the records that not in the **menu table**. How to write that condition. I am working on it for a long time I am new to this situation. Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I want to suggest something that,

You are doing lots of database operations in foreach loop, which is not good for performance factor. You should first prepare query and then fire at once.

And other thing is that you are checking for records in database via php code and firing query. Rather than that you should do checking in MySQL only.

Here below is a rough idea of solution you can implement with according to your own parameters.

You can write a query that checks for existing records in table if not exists then insert it to table.

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS
```

this can be used in your query.

And one more you can append more queries and fire it at once using [`insert_batch`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=insert_batch#CI_DB_query_builder::insert_batch) function of codeigniter.

Rough structure would be like

```
foreach(x as y) {
     //push all data to array $queries;
}
$this->db->insert_batch('menu',$queries);
```